# What is the difference between !! and !!as.symbol?

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider this example:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(a=1:5,b=6:10)

> df
  a  b
1 1  6
2 2  7
3 3  8
4 4  9
5 5 10
```

```
colname <- "a"
df |> filter(!!as.symbol(colname)<3)

  a b
1 1 6
2 2 7
```

```
df |> filter(!!colname<3)
[1] a b
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

What does applying `!!` to a string rather than a symbol achieves, and why does it return an empty dataframe instead of an error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us expand the example first with the `df` in the question and then `df2` which is `df` plus an extra column called `colname`.

Whether or not `colname` is a column:

- `!!as.symbol(colname)` returns the value of the `a` column as a vector
- `!!colname` returns the character string `"a"`
- !!"colname" returns the character string `"colname"`

However, `!!as.symbol("colname")` acts differently depending on whether `colname` is a column name or not.

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:5,b=6:10);
colname <- "a"
look <- function(x) { str(x); x }

df |> filter(look(!!as.symbol(colname)) < 3) |> invisible()
##  int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
df |> filter(look(!!as.symbol("colname")) < 3) |> invisible()
##  chr "a"
df |> filter(look(!!colname) == "a") |> invisible()
##  chr "a"
df |> filter(look(!!"colname") == "a") |> invisible()
##  chr "colname"

####

df2 <- data.frame(a=1:5,b=6:10,colname=c(11:14, 1));
colname <- "a"
look <- function(x) { str(x); x }
 
df2 |> filter(look(!!as.symbol(colname)) < 3) |> invisible()
##  int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
df2 |> filter(look(!!as.symbol("colname")) < 3) |> invisible()
##  num [1:5] 11 12 13 14 1
df2 |> filter(look(!!colname) == "a") |> invisible()
##  chr "a"
df2 |> filter(look(!!"colname") == "a") |> invisible()
##  chr "colname"
```

Comment: I still wonder how, when `colname <- 2`, dplyr knows to return the second column (numeric 2) from `select(!!colname)`, while base R returns all columns (logical `TRUE`, regarding `!!` as a double negation) when selecting `df[!!colname]`.

Comment: select first evaluates its arguments using eval_select from the tidyselect package.  Base does not.

Comment: And the use of `|> invisible()` in the above?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the help page of `!!` (`help("!!")`), this would redirect you to the function `inject` in the package `rlang`. And by combining `inject` and `subsititute` functions, you can logically rebuild the expression that is evaluated.

Using `!!colname < 3)`, where `colname = "a"`, your are checking if the string `"a"` is lower than 3 while with `!!as.symbol(colname) < 3)` you are checking if the variable named `a` is lower than 3.

Considering your example, the following expressions show the difference between the two cases after `colname` is substituted:

```
colname <- "a"

### Using !!colname < 3) ###
rlang::inject(substitute(
  df |> 
    filter(!!colname < 3)
))
# filter(df, "a" < 3)                                 # contains a string "a"


### Using !!as.symbol(colname) < 3) ###
rlang::inject(substitute(
  df |> 
    filter(!!as.symbol(colname) < 3)
))
# filter(df, a < 3)                                   # contains a variable a
```